# Why don't Go (lang) binaries show up in `which`, `whereis`, and similar tools?

Tags: shell, golang

I've installed a couple of Go utilities via `go get -u github.com/[owner]/[repo]` and I don't understand why they don't honor standard shell conventions. The utility I installed had no trace of anything in the directory the command was run from, nor any output indicating anything, so I looked for it via a fairly standard means, and couldn't find it, yet I was always able to run it:

```
~ $ which hey
~ $ hey
Usage: hey [options...] <url>

Options:
  -n  Number of requests to run. Default is 200.
  -c  Number of requests to run concurrently. Total number of requests cannot be smaller than the concurrency level. Default is 50.
[…]
```

I only figured it out because I noticed that the tail end of my `$PATH` includes `:~/go/bin`, and sure enough the three go utilities I've installed are present there. Saved me from a long winded `find` search.

How do Go installed binaries escape standard file lookup means, yet remain able to run?

This is occurring on a standard bash shell, as shipped with macOS High Sierra (10.13.6).

```
~ $ type -a hey
hey is /Users/jsalaz/go/bin/hey
~ $ type -a which
which is /usr/bin/which
```

Comment: Assuming it's bash, can you show the output of `type -a hey` and even `type -a which`?

Comment: I really don't use `type` enough, I think I can count the number of times on one hand. I tend to do direct inspection with `ls` flags to determine it's attributes. Will definitely store `type -a` away for future use…

Comment: Attributes? That's... not exactly what `type` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, using `~/go/bin` as a $PATH component relies on a nonstandard (perhaps GNU?) extension.

- Whenever your shell (bash) searches for binaries, it expands the `~/` prefix to your home directory's path. You can see that `type` (which is built into the shell) finds the Go program just fine.
- Meanwhile, the `/usr/bin/which` command (which is provided by macOS and is not part of the shell) *does not* perform this expansion, because no such thing was specified in The Open Group's [official description of how $PATH should work](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html).

In other words, the `~/` prefix is part of the shell language, but *not* part of the general OS-wide path syntax. In all other places, including $PATH (which is not limited to shells!), it simply means a directory named `~`.

When setting $PATH, you need to make sure the paths are expanded at assignment time:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/go/bin
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/go/bin"
```

This one won't work:

```
PATH="$PATH:~/go/bin"
```

Comment: That’s, incredible. And true, in the past I’ve always used `$HOME` in `$PATH` and any other shell environment variables. This is no doubt another BSD coreutils (which macOS ships) vs GNU coreutils discrepancy. I need to test this on a Linux machine now too.